# Wordpress Admin area - TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(".tab_content")', '$' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with the following js error in wordpress admin area only because instead of using the wordpress default jquery I'm calling latest jquery api from jquery.com like `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> </script>` so I have removed default wordpress jquery file via functions.php and loading this one instead. Above functionality is coming from theme but below I have my plugin page where I have the js and tabs which are not working fine.

```
<div class="wrap">
   <h2> PAGE TITLE </h2>

   <div class="metabox-holder postbox-container" style="width:100%;">
      <ul class="tabs">
         <li class="active" rel="feed">FIRST TAB</li>
         <li rel="gora">SECOND TAB</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab_container" style="text-align: left;">
         <div id="feed" class="tab_content">

             <------ tab 1 content ------>

         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tab_container" style="text-align: left;">
         <div id="gora" class="tab_content">

            <------ tab 2 content ------>

         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tab_container" style="text-align: left;">
         <div id="article" class="tab_content">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

The js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#" + activeTab).show();
    });
});
```

I tried also:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#" + activeTab).show();
    });
});
```

But I'm still getting the `TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(".tab_content")', '$' is undefined)` in the console.

Is there anything wrong in the codes, so the tabs are working with default wordpress themes but with my custom theme where I use `//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` it doesn't work.

**jQuery Migrate is also enabled in wp-admin area.**
Thankyou!

Comment: Your plugin js load before jquery library so you got that error.

Comment: no the jquery is loaded before the js code in the source but both are below the head tag so in the body.

Comment: Can you show  how you load your script.

Answer (score 1):

in wordpress if you want use jquery , use this

`$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//your code jquery
 });`

Comment: oh try this at top `$.noConflict();`

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of reasons for this.

1) You are not loading jQuery on time so I suggest you put it into a head tag on the page where you want to use it.

2) From this path you gave `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> </script>` it seems that you are not importing it into your project correctly. If it is downloaded jQuery file, see that the path is correct. Or, you can use CDN version for this like this: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: but jquery works fine in the fron and with other plugins